# Preserve checked checkboxes after post in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, checkbox

I want to keep the form fields preserved after submitting the form. I can preserve all the fields except the checked checkboxes

Here is my form action **view**:

```
def student_submit_info(request):
    form_values = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        print form.is_valid()
        form_values = getDetails(request)
        if form.is_valid():
            print request.user.username
            student = Student.objects.get(user=request.user)
            // saving student to DB
            saveDetails(request, student, form_values)
    return render_to_response('student.html', form_values, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def getDetails(request):
  #fetch input data
   form_values = {}
   form_values['first_name'] = request.POST['first_name']
   form_values['last_name'] = request.POST['last_name']
   form_values['skills'] = request.POST.getlist('skills[]')
   return form_values
```

I would want to preserve skills (checkbox), here's a part of my **template**

```
skill1<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" checked value="skill1"/>
skill2<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="skill2"/>
skill3<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="skill3"/>
```

Comment: Why do you use `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)` and not simply request.user ?

Comment: Where does your `form` variable come from ?

Comment: I don't think Django forms support the `name="something[]"` notation. It would probably be simpler to use built-in widgets, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381300/django-forms-list-of-checkboxes-list-of-radiobuttons

Answer (score 1):

You should make a [custom django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/) to handle easily forms, example of a post view:

```
def post_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        do_something()
    render(request, 'your_temp', {'MyForm': MyForm'})
```

With this kind of snippet, data in form will always be those sent.
You can override `is_valid()` for empty skill checkboxes.

Comment: I missed the lineform = StudentForm(request.POST). Edited. I also added   <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="c" {% if "c" in skills %}checked{% endif %}/> in my template. Thanks for the request.user tip!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, use CBV's and ModelForms to make the process simpler.
Combine a listview (or similar) and add your form via context.
Then in get_context_data of your CBV:

```
form_values = {}
#Simpler code below for accessing post dictionary
for key, value in self.request.POST.items():
            if value == 'on':
                form_values[key] = value

context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
# You need to add form_values to make it accessible in the forms.py
context['form'] = YourFormName(form_values)
```

Then, in your forms.py (I'm hoping you use modelforms):

```
def __init__(self, filters, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourFormName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if len(form_values) > 0: 
            for field_name in self.fields:
                if field_name in filters:
                    self.fields[field_name].widget = forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'checked': True})
```

I hope this helps.